# how to send image to server in react expo

Tags: react-native, bitmap, expo, imagepicker

I sent the image to server by bitmap in android studio this way:

```
  bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), resultUri);

       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap , 500, 500, true);
        bitmap .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Now in expo I have the **uri** using image picker ,How can I do this in react expo?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a formData if backend using RestAPI like this

```
 // Upload the image using the fetch and FormData APIs
  let formData = new FormData();
  // Assume "photo" is the name of the form field the server expects
  formData.append('photo', { uri: localUri, name: filename, type });

  return await fetch(YOUR_SERVER_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  });
```

Comment: thanks for your attention, how can I use   "Content-Type": "application/json",? I need to send other data to register service.@pho